# Word frequency (or tag usage) over time (Trending)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching, statistics

I'd like to see how many times people refer to a specific technology over time.  Trending via question text, or better yet, tag usage may provide interesting results.

**Bounty:** I am offering a bounty  to anyone who can point me to a specific query on the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that gives the trending tags/topics on SO and the other SE sites.

Comment: there is also this [tag trends by week](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/tags/) utility from Greg Hewgill

Comment: Thanks @geronimo looks like a nice feature, though it only supports 3 tags for comparison (no more)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can craft the SQL to get this kind of information from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer at http://odata.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was not expecting OData to be from Microsoft!  I have a bit of a learning curve ahead.  Hopefully I can find some C# samples...

Comment: @MakerOfThings7: You don't need to use the OData endpoint, you can just "Compose Query" to your heart's content.